# select *, group by ID.. cannot group by * --- how to merge summary statistics?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I used to use SAS a lot. So this is annoying for me trying to do this in Access 2016.
Table example:

```
ID        Name      Sport
__________________________
99       Jack         Soccer
99       Jack Jim     Baseball
54       Bob          Basketball
```

I want to select *, count the ID and group by the ID, so I can add in a where to show duplicate IDs because of a cartesian match.

What I want is this:

```
ID        Name      Sport          ID_Count
______________________________________________
99       Jack         Soccer           2
99       Jack Jim     Baseball         2  
54       Bob          Basketball       1
```

However, I get the message that I cannot group by *, because for some reason merging summary statistics is not possible but cartesian products in other instances are.  Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: though the outcome is similar, SAS and SQL are a long ways apart.  Best to nearly forget SAS terminology and practice when using SQL (merging is a far different term in SQL than SAS for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in your ms access 2016 :

```
Select yourtable.*, q1.ID_Count from yourtable 
join (select id, count(id) as ID_Count from yourtable group by id having count(id)>1) q1 
on yourtable.id = q1.id
```

Comment: I upvoted you, but it didn't go anything since I'm a pleb.

Comment: it says it doesn't show anything because I have less than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

SAS's remerging of aggregation results in proc sql is non-standard syntax.  Standard SQL supports window functions, which do this.  Alas, MS Access does not support this standard functionality.

A similar method is a `JOIN` on an aggregation query or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id) as id_count
from t;
```

The ANSI standard functionality is:

```
select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as id_count
from t;
```

Comment: (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id) as id_count....

When you say select count from "t t2" does that mean it is counting from both tables?

Comment: I tried to use the ANSI version, but I am getting the error that there is a missing operator in the partition by ID

Comment: nevermind.. i just made two tables and joined on the ID. Guess I will have to start getting used to going through more steps

Comment: @Mitchell . . . The correlated subquery is pretty close to what SAS is doing.

Comment: just trying to understand how the count(*) is for both t and t2 in your example

Answer (score 0):

Why use * when you can just list out your fields and still use the group by?

```
SELECT ID, Name, Sport, Count([ID]) as [ID_Count]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID, Name, Sport
```

I would stay away from trying to use * in a group by query in MS Access. Could complicate simple tasks.

Comment: if I group by all 3 parameters, wouldn't the ID count always be 1 since each row is unique?