# How to sum values across a group and then assign the result to each individual within the group in SAS

Tags: sas, sum, retain

I have unique groups that consist of 2 or 3 people. Each person has a value for a variable X (or missing). For each group, i want to sum the values for all observations in that group AND assign the result to each person in the group.

the have dataset looks like this

`group ID     X

1     110     2.5
1     111     1.0
1     112     0.0
2     210     .
2     211     5.6
3     212     2.0
3     213     1.5
4     310     .
4     311     7.2
4     312     2.1`

And the dataset I want with a new variable Y loos like this:

`group ID     X       Y
1     110     2.5     3.5
1     111     1.0     3.5
1     112     0.0     3.5
2     210     .       5.6
2     211     5.6     5.6
3     212     2.0     3.5
3     213     1.5     3.5
4     310     .       9.3
4     311     7.2     9.3
4     312     2.1     9.3`

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: So what did you try? In what way was it not successful?

Comment: Try `Proc SQL` with aggregate `sum` function and `group by`, or `proc means` with `output` followed by `data` step with `merge`, or data step with a *DOW* loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select \*, group by ID.. cannot group by \* --- how to merge summary statistics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817041/select-group-by-id-cannot-group-by-how-to-merge-summary-statistics)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table is called "ds":

```
PROC SQL;
    SELECT group, ID, x, sum(x) AS y
    FROM DS
    GROUP BY group;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you data is already sorted Dow loop solution and mean followed by merge solution as suggested by @Richard in comments.

```
  /*DOW LOOP solution*/

   data want;
 do until(last.group);
 set have;
 by group;
if first.group then Y=X;
 else Y+X;
  end;
 do until(last.group);
   set have;
 by group;
output;
end;
run;

/* mean followed by merge solution*/
proc means data = have nway noprint;
class group;
var X;
output out=have1 ( keep = Group Y) sum=Y;
 run;



data want;
merge have have1;
by group;
run;
```

Comment: Why not just use the `nway` option on `proc means` statement?  If you eliminate output rows with `group=.` then you will not get row that has the sum of X for observations with missing group variable.

Answer (score 1):

@Kiran, your coding of serial `do … until` with `last.group` as the terminus condition does not work because the `last.group=1` state persists despite the `set;by;` within the second loop, and thus the second loop only iterates once.

A better solution, as long espoused by Dorfman, is the pattern of a first loop computing group size with `1 by 1`, followed by a second loop explicitly looping `1 to _n_`

```
data have; input
group ID     X; datalines;
1     110     2.5
1     111     1.0
1     112     0.0
2     210     .
2     211     5.6
3     212     2.0
3     213     1.5
4     310     .
4     311     7.2
4     312     2.1
run;

data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.group);
    set have;
    by group;
    groupsum = sum(groupsum,x);
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_ ;
    set have;
    output;  * group related computation result gets carried into the output data set (want);
  end;
run;
```

The pattern part `do _n_ = 1 to _n_` becomes more understandable when the coder realizes that SAS data step evaluates the *start*, *stop* and *by* values for the loop prior to actually iterating the loop.